# Дефект локализации в списке действий вкладки Активность в профиле

Tags: дефект, локализация, профиль-участника

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Родительный падеж здесь не уместен: `проверок → проверки`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Строка: `74dcb1cec50854d2f880279f3dd19da9`.

В английском варианте там просто **reviews**. У них нет падежей и нет наших проблем. У нас этот ключ может использоваться в разных падежах (`reviews` → `проверки`, `10 reviews` → `10 проверок`).

Поэтому, не уверен, что просто смена перевода на **проверки** — хорошее решение.

Comment: Спасибо! Просто для понимания - почему, например  "правки", а не "правок"? Вроде по аналогии - "10 правок".

Comment: У правок в оригинале "Edits". Этому переводу уже 4 года. А вот перевод "проверок" Aer пару месяцев назад добавил всего лишь. Нужно его спрашивать.

Comment: Раз нужно, спросим. @Aer ^^^ ?

Comment: @0xdb сомневаюсь, что так можно его призвать.

Comment: А как ещё? Обходит стороной?

Comment: @0xdb в нашем чате пингануть, или зайти в чат РЯ и там пингануть, или на мете РЯ этот же вопрос задать.

Comment: А это вообще проблема перевода? Если нет ключа для иминительного падежа, то его надо добавить. Есть же и "правки" и "правок".

Comment: @0xdb не знаю, у Aer должна была причина зачем-то перевод делать в родительном падеже. Если он это сделал по ошибке, то нужно просто поменять на "проверки". Если есть место, где нужен родительный падеж, тогда нужно попросить разработчиков разделить ключи.

Comment: Хорошо, проблематику понял.